# Is it safe to store classified information in a session variable?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Im just wondering if it is safe to save classified informations such as passwords. and if not, what are the potential security issues?im currently developing a website with a login. after the users login im planning to save all the information about the user to a session variable so i dont have to query it in the database every time i want to access required information from the users thats why im asking this question.

Comment: You should at least salt the passwords or have some kind of protection, instead of just storing plaintext, especially if it's sensitive.

Comment: yes, but is this a sane approach? You would have to ensure that session, memory and db stay in sync.

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question.

Comment: Sessions are normally stored un-encrypted (plain) on disk. If you are concerned about security and you're using sessions, take a look for transparent session encryption and cookie encryption with the suhosin extension.

Answer (score 1):

"Safe" is a relative word, but information stored in the `_SESSION` is approximately as safe as information stored in the database .. only someone who legitimately hacked your server would be able to access it.

That said, sessions themselves may not be safe.  A malicious user may be able fixate or hijack a session.  This does not give them information to the contents of `_SESSION` directly, but it still allows them to act as another user.  You should take necessary precautions .. honestly this is not a reason not to use sessions.

One precaution would be to *not* store the user's password in `_SESSION`.  Why would you need to do that?

As long as you don't `var_dump()` `_SESSION` or wantonly display session values, then `_SESSION` is as safe as the DB.  Still, you should limit the information stored in `_SESSION` to what you actually need for a variety of reasons (not just security ones).

Answer (score 1):

Data contained in `$_SESSION` usually is stored in the file-system .. most common location is */tmp/* folder ( there are some solutions when you keep it in cache, noSQL or SQL ).

So, by default, data there is as safe as your server is. If your server is compromised, then confidential info in session data is the least of your problems.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in storing passwords in the session.
So, safe or not safe - it doesn't matter at all (however it is obviously not safe). Just don't store it.

> so i dont have to query it in the database

Why? What's wrong with querying a database?

> every time i want to access required information

Okay, but password? What it could be needed for?

Comment: I have a form which loads information about the user upon login.Upon logging in thats when i store all the information from the database in the session variable which includes the password. then i just used the session variable to echo it in the form to display the informations. i know you were being rhetorical. i just explained what i was planning on doing.any way cheers.thanks for the reply!:)

Comment: I am not being rhetorical. And I don't understand what are you talking about. There is no absolutely no point in displaying password in the form. Nobody is doing that. And what's the point in displaying user info in the form? You are doing some strange things and you'd better you change your weird setup to something sane.

Answer (score 0):

## NOT SAFE

> **Session hijacking**, sometimes also known as cookie hijacking is the exploitation of a >valid computer session — sometimes also called a session key — to gain unauthorized access >to information or services in a computer system. — Wikipedia

It’s the act of stealing a customer’s session ID, by which they can access your web application as if they’re that customer.

**Is this possible? How do they get that session ID which is in the user’s browser?**

> Yes it’s possible. The two cookie properties (or flags) HttpOnly and Secure are the reason for this.